# How to click an element from a dropdown with capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

I'm having trouble getting an element to click from capybara.  I've searched through other posts and nothing was helping me solve my problem.

The solution that I thought looked the best is this:
`select "Manage Users", :from => "accountLink"`

But in return I get this:

```
Admin Abilities Creates a new user
 Failure/Error: select "Manage Users", :from => "accountLink"
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find select box "accountLink"
 # ./spec/features/admin_abilities_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/features/admin_abilities_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the rendered html:

```
 <li class='dropdown' id='accountLink'>
          <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>
            Account
            <b class='caret'></b>
          </a>
          <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
            <li id='accountLink'><a href="/users/edit">Change Info</a></li>
            <li id='impersonateLink'><a href="/staff/impersonate">Impersonate User</a></li>
            <li id='adminLink'><a href="/admin/users">Manage Users</a></li>
            <li><a href="/toggle_fakenames">Toggle Fake Names</a></li>
            <li id='logoutLink'><a href="/users/sign_out" data-method="delete" data-placement="right" data-title="Logged in as cayce.balara@pragmatim.com" rel="tooltip nofollow">Logout</a></li>
            <li class='divider'></li>
            <li class='disabled'><a href="#" disabled="disabled">Server Default</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

Can someone help me get capybara to click this element?

Answer (score 0):

`select 'Manage Users'` is looking for a checkbox, but your dropdown items are simply anchor tags in a list. So you can just click on them:

```
find('a.dropdown-toggle').click # assuming you only have one a.dropdown-toggle
click_on 'Manage Users' # or find('#adminLink a').click
```

Answer (score 0):

Some things that should work

```
click_link "Manage Users"

find(#adminLink).click
```

Note: Your html seems to be using id's badly. Their should only be one instance of an id on a page.